# Rails based on condition assign model to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following method:

```
def self.get_rec(product, type)
  if type == "A"
    db = Pwvav
  elsif type == "B"
    db = Pwbab
  elsif type == "C"
    db = Pwvub
  else type == "D"
    db = Tic
    db.find_by_id(product.id).recommendation.split(",").each do |rec|
      r = Recommendation.find_by_id(rec)
      pr = Model.new(:rating_set => rating_set.id, :recommendation_id => r.id, :product_id => product.id)
      pr.save
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the method, the `db.find`  is not working as I expect. If replace `db.find_by_id(product.id).recommendation.split(",").each do |rec|` with `Pwvav.find_by_id(product.id).recommendation.split(",").each do |rec|` for example, it works. How do I chose which model to call based on what the `type` equals?

Comment: I dont get an error, the `pr` is not created. Also, If i print something out after the if/elsif it does not output.

Comment: is "Model" is model name?

Comment: edited your code where you'll see that the find_by_id is inside the else block

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Will accept your answer in 2mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error, if I'm right, is with your structure.  the `find_by_id` code is inside the else so it doesn't create other records when type is not 'D'.  Try the following code which I think is more readable

```
def self.get_rec(product, type)
  db = case type
       when 'A' then Pwvav
       when 'B' then Pwbab
       when 'C' then Pwvub
       when 'D' then Tic
       end

  db.find_by_id(product.id).recommendation.split(",").each do |rec|
    r = Recommendation.find_by_id(rec)
    pr = Model.new(rating_set: rating_set.id, recommendation_id: r.id, product_id => product.id)
    pr.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't close your "if - elsif - else condition, then the last block with the find, find_by_id and your new is only executed when type == 'D'.

Insert an end after

```
db = Tic
```